# Shogun missing java jar in Linux

Tags: java, shogun

I would like to use shogun 6.1.3 (libshogun) in linux (e.g ubuntu) with Java. I could not find any linux repository which would contain the shogun.jar and the related /cli/shogun/libshogun.so.

Is it possible that the only way to get this is by installing from source?

(In OX X I get this automatically when I install shogun with brew)

Comment: See quicklinks from http://shogun-toolbox.org/install. Here is different instructions for different Linux distros.

Comment: The repositories only contain /usr/local/lib/libshogun.so but not /usr/lib/cli/shogun/libshogun.so.